# How to read write from Encrypted Amazon ElastiCache Redis Server without using stunnel?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

I have Amazon ElastiCache Redis Server used as the Encryption in-transit and Encryption at-rest. From what I have read in the document:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elasticache-connect-redis-node/
We need to use install stunnel and use through the localhost to access the server from our local environment or EC2 instance. Is there any way to avoid it? I am using **Redisson** as Java API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found a way to interact with AWS Encrypted Redis cluster without using  Stunnel. Found that we can  do it using  prefix "rediss://" instead of "redis://" (extra s denotes it as a SSL client) while setting the address through the API.